# wget - исключение заданной директории в случайных местах при скачивании с FTP

Tags: linux, wget

Есть bash скрипт с примерно таким содержанием:

```
SKIP="*.sql.gz,*.cache*"
SKIPDIRS="/thumbs/"

wget -o ${LOG} -P ${OUTPUTDIR} --reject ${SKIP} --reject-regex ${SKIPDIRS} --recursive -nv -nc -nH --level=0 ${FROM} --ftp-user=${USER} --ftp-password=${PWD} --passive-ftp=on
```

И на FTP есть примерно такая структура каталогов:

```
\
 -something1
 -something2
 -images
  -cat1
   -thumbs
  -cat2
   -thumbs
   -subcat21
   -subcat22
    -thumbs
    -subcat221
     -thumbs
  -catN
   -thumbs
```

Число директорий внутри /images/, их наименования, вложенность, наличие вложенных /thumbs/ все может быть произвольным. **Задача: выдрать это все с FTP wget'ом, исключая все директории /thumbs/ вместе с содержимым.**

В приведенном выше скрипте все работает отлично кроме того, что директории thumbs скачиваются полностью с содержимым.

Пробовал так (прочие параметры не менял):

```
SKIPDIRS="/thumbs/"
wget --reject-regex ${SKIPDIRS}

SKIPDIRS=".*/thumbs/.*"
wget --reject-regex ${SKIPDIRS}

SKIPDIRS="thumbs"
wget --exclude-directories ${SKIPDIRS}

SKIPDIRS="*/thumbs/*"
wget --exclude-directories ${SKIPDIRS}
```

и даже так

```
SKIP="*.sql.gz,*.cache*,*/thumbs/*"
wget --reject ${SKIP}
```

Все бесполезно, /thumbs/ скачиваются вместе с содержимым. --exclude-directories вообще от корня работает, но я так не могу, все произвольно.

Как правильно задать исключение?

Comment: пишут, что старый wget не позволял использовать одновременно -R и --reject-regex, кроме того можно параметром указать тип регулярки (в линуксе их 2 типа), можно попробовать звездочки спереди и сзади поставить. подробнее [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231736/how-to-use-regular-expressions-in-wget-for-rejecting-files/21382873). в крайнем случае использовать curl

Comment: @Алексей Обухов, спасибо, сейчас попробую. Ссылку я читал ранее, а вот то, что нельзя совмещать -R  и --reject-regex не знал. Моя версия wget 1.19.1, но есть некоторое "осложнение" в том, что данный wget крутится на Синолоджи. Кто знает, что они туда напихали? Попробую убрать -R, и про тип регулярок надо попробовать.. Если что, придется на curl заморачиваться, ну или смириться с несколькими лишними тысячами файлов.

Comment: Все, сдаюсь(( Как только не извращался, какие комбинации масок и параметров, смены типов regex не пробовал - не получается. Такое ощущение, что параметр --reject-regex полностью игнорируется при скачивании, хотя валидность регулярки все же проверяется. Но через этот этот параметр даже файлы из корня не удалось исключить, не то что директории. Либо я чего-то не догоняю, либо wget не работает как надо (может версия старовата).